# Is there any way to publish game for android

Tags: game-engine

I know about blender for android but that's just blender player and no export/publish for android.

Is there any way for build a single android apk from blender game?
**No Gamekit**, is there another way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the game-engine was ported to Android for a GSOC project, but this didn't make it into an official release yet.

There is however work being done for Blender to use [EGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EGL_%28API%29), which will help Blender run on Android and Wayland in the future. (The `soc-2014-viewport_fx` branch).